# Bézier curve calculation

Tags: math, graphics, bezier

I'm trying to work a simple Bezier curve but I just can't understand the maths behind it, if someone could explain to me this simple Bezier curve it would be awesome :)

We have

```
point1
X: 0
Y: 0

point2
X: 100
Y: 100

control point1
X: 0
Y: 100
```

So basically we have a line that starts from the top left and will get a diagonal line from the top left to the bottom right of a 100 by 100 pixel square, but now I want to try and pull that line to the control point at X position 0 and Y position 100, could someone explain to me the simple maths that happens here, can if possible show the calculations with my values :).

Thank you

P.S. a basic picture

[image]

UPDATE

Here is my simple javascript code that uses the equation

```
canvasHolder = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
canvas = canvasHolder.getContext('2d');

var deltaT = 0.10;
var point1 = new Point(300,300);
var point2 = new Point(400,400);
var controlPoint1 = new Point(100,200);
//Bezier cruve
for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    var t = (i/10) * 0.1;
    var xPos = ( 1.0 * - t*t ) * point1.x + 2.0 * ( 1 - t ) * t * controlPoint1.x + t * t * point2.x;
    var yPos = ( 1.0 * - t*t ) * point1.y + 2.0 * ( 1 - t ) * t * controlPoint1.y + t * t * point2.y;
    console.log( "xPos = " + xPos + ", yPos = " + yPos );
    var particle = new Particle( "circle", xPos, yPos, 5, "#FF0000", "#333333");
    particles[i] = particle;
}
```

here is the output for that

```
xPos = 0, yPos = 0 bezierCurve.js:35
xPos = 1.9900000000000004, yPos = 3.970000000000001 bezierCurve.js:35
xPos = 3.9600000000000004, yPos = 7.880000000000001 bezierCurve.js:35
xPos = 5.909999999999999, yPos = 11.729999999999999 bezierCurve.js:35
xPos = 7.840000000000001, yPos = 15.520000000000001 bezierCurve.js:35
xPos = 9.75, yPos = 19.25 bezierCurve.js:35
xPos = 11.639999999999997, yPos = 22.919999999999998 bezierCurve.js:35
xPos = 13.509999999999996, yPos = 26.529999999999998 bezierCurve.js:35
xPos = 15.360000000000003, yPos = 30.080000000000005 bezierCurve.js:35
xPos = 17.190000000000005, yPos = 33.57000000000001
```

any reason on why I am getting this result

Edit,

its ok i was doing this

```
var xPos = ( 1.0 * - t*t ) * point1.x + 2.0 * ( 1 - t ) * t * controlPoint1.x + t * t * point2.x;
```

when it is this

```
var xPos = ( 1.0 - t*t ) * point1.x + 2.0 * ( 1 - t ) * t * controlPoint1.x + t * t * point2.x;
```

Comment: Are you hoping to draw the curve or move an object along it?

Comment: Move an object a long it, I do apologize for the lack of response, been very busy and at work so :( But cheers for all the answers i will take a in-depth look tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bezier curves are parametric curves. That means that you will have 2 equations: 1 for the x coordinates over the curve, and the other for the y coordinates over the curve.

In this case, you're working with a quadratic bezier. The equation for [quadratic beziers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve#Quadratic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) is:

> x(t) = (1.0 - t^2) * p0.x + 2.0 * (1 - t) * t * p1.x + t^2 * p2.x;
>   y(t) = (1.0 - t^2) * p0.y + 2.0 * (1 - t) * t * p1.y + t^2 * p2.y;

In this case, p0 is the start point, p1 is the control point, and p2 is the end point.

t varies from 0 to 1 over the curve. So to draw it using a standard line drawing function, you'd do the following:

```
float numDivisions = 100.0; // <- You need to decide what this value should be. See below
float t;
float deltaT = t / numDivisions;
MoveTo (p0.x, p0.y);
for (t = 0; t <= 1.0; t += deltaT)
{
    x = (1.0 - t*t) * p0.x + 2.0 * (1 - t) * t * p1.x + t * t * p2.x;
    y = (1.0 - t*t) * p0.y + 2.0 * (1 - t) * t * p1.y + t * t * p2.y;
    LineTo (x, y);
}
```

The numDivisions will control the resolution of the curves. If you only have 3 divisions, you'll get the start point, 1 point in the middle (parametrically speaking), and the end point. If you use 10,000 points, you'll probably draw much more than you need to. A rule of thumb is that the straight lines connecting the points will always be longer than the actual curve, so you never need to use a number of divisions greater than that. (You can use a Euclidean distance between the points.)

Comment: So if we had P0 x:0, y:0, P1 x:0 y:100 and P2 x:100 y:100, if we had numVidivisions = 10, we would go the for loop 10 times, so for the second iteration T = 0.1, are thess the correct values in the equation? x = (1.0 - 0.1*0.1) * 0 + 2.0 * (1 - 0.1) * 0.1 * 0 + 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.1 * 100) is that correct for X?

Comment: Just did some simple tests and that to me gives the correct results :)  I just set t to be 0.5 and wanted to see if x is 25 and y is 75 and indeed it is :) cheers for the help

Comment: But just quickly what if I wanted to add like 5 control points?

Comment: For quadratic beziers, there's only ever a single control point between the 2 endpoints. You can, however, add more quadratic bezier segments before or after the current one. So you'd have start point, control point, end point (which is also the next start point), control point, end point (which is also the next start point), etc.

Comment: Can you take a look at my javascript code I have posted in my question?

Comment: With the correction you made in the edit, it looks valid to me. Are your new results correct? When `t` is 0, `xPos` should be 300 and `yPos` should also be 300.

Comment: indeed, it looks sweet :D making an object move from point to point will look very nice

Answer (score 0):

You can derive the parametric equations for a bezier curve from the geometrical representation:

```
  (a)--A-----(c)
          x    \
                C
                 \
                  \
                  (b)
```

Draw a line from a->c->b

Subdivide the line from `a->c` by a point *A*, where *A* = *t* *(*c*- *a*) + *a*, i.e. *t* units from *a* towards *c* (0<=*t*<=1). Using the same ratio *t*, advance from c towards b, the same *t* units (point C).

(Recursively) subdivide A->C to sections of *t* and *1-t*, placing the point *x* at the splitting point. That's the true point located at the Bezier curve.

The same procedure can be used to generate cubic Beziers -- adding one more step to the process.

Summing: (a = { ax, ay }), A = { Ax, Ay }) etc.

```
  A = (c-a)*t + a = { cx-ax * t + ax, cy-ay * t + ay }
  B = (b-c)*t + c = { bx-cx * t + cx, by-cy * t + cy }       
  x = (C-A)*t + A = { Cx-Ax * t + Ax, Cy-Ay * y + Ay }
```

(Notice, that if a = { ax, ay, az } i.e. a 3D point, the same principle holds)

These formulas can now be combined to produce a closed form equation for Cx, Cy, [Cz] as a quadratic function of *t*, and constants ax,ay,cx,cy,bx,by, as in the first answer by [user1118321](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21962457/1716339).